# How to achieve multiple delete from rest high level client 6.2.4?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

The following code only works for ElasticSearchClient. I want to use RestHighLevelClient 6.2.4 version.

```
BulkByScrollResponse response = 
    DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(restClient)
                       .source("persons")
                       .get();
            long deleted = response.getDeleted();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Delete by Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) is only supported in the RestHighLevelClient as of [version 6.5 and above](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.5/java-rest-high-document-delete-by-query.html).

If you're using 6.2.4, you can still call the `_delete_by_query` endpoint using the low-level client, though:

```
Response response = restClient.performRequest("POST", "/persons/_delete_by_query"); 
String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
// parse the JSON and do something
```

If you need to pass in a query you can do it like this:

```
Map<String, String> params = Collections.emptyMap();
String jsonString = "{ \"query\": { \"range\" : { \"age\" : { \"gte\" : 10 } } } }";
HttpEntity query = new NStringEntity(jsonString, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

Response response = restClient.performRequest("POST", "/persons/_delete_by_query", params, query); 
String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
// parse the JSON and do something
```

Comment: great suggestion I'm fairly new to elastic search : can you please let me know how to pass{
  "query": {
    "range" : {
        "age" : {
           "gte" : 10
        }
    }
  }
} in your answer. also note i will have an array of indices and a gte dte

Comment: Thanks a lot for making it so easy for me.

Comment: I have one more question : what if i had multiple indices to delete how can i use a list of indices?

Comment: just replace `persons` by `persons,index2,index3,etc`

Comment: Please ask a new question

Comment: is it ok if i send params as empty map